# Why my app crashes with NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception, cardview

I've tried to create simple app with using CardView. It is my first steps with android and java so for you this problem might be very easy to fix. Ok then, when i tried to open app on AVD it's crash.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GridLayout mainGrid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

    setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
}
private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
        CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
        final int finalI = i;
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,bmistart.class);
                intent.putExtra("info","This is activity from card item index  "+finalI);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the problem:

```
2020-03-24 21:47:47.986 10136-10136/com.example.mobilefittrener E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mobilefittrener, PID: 10136
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mobilefittrener/com.example.mobilefittrener.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.GridLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.GridLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.mobilefittrener.MainActivity.setSingleEvent(MainActivity.java:26)
    at com.example.mobilefittrener.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

2020-03-24 21:47:48.013 10136-10136/com.example.mobilefittrener I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10136 SIG: 9

My MainActivity xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGrid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/nazwa"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="23dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        >


        <!--Kolumna 1 Wiersz 1-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/bmi"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--Kolumna 2 Wiersz 1-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/weightlifter" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--Kolumna 1 Wiersz 2-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/climb"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--Kolumna 2 Wiersz 2-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/alarm"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--Kolumna 1 Wiersz 3-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/diet"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--Kolumna 2 Wiersz 3-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/quality"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It's my first post, don't be mean please :)

Comment: share your MainActivity xml

Comment: Make sure that: findViewById(R.id.mainGrid) actually exists.

Comment: Looks like mainGrid is not found in view by that id.

Comment: It says `mainGrid` does not exist inside the layout `R.layout.activity_main`

Answer (score 0):

My MainActivity xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGrid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/nazwa"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="23dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        >


        <!--Kolumna 1 Wiersz 1-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/bmi"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--Kolumna 2 Wiersz 1-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/weightlifter" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--Kolumna 1 Wiersz 2-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/climb"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--Kolumna 2 Wiersz 2-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/alarm"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--Kolumna 1 Wiersz 3-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/diet"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!--Kolumna 2 Wiersz 3-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/quality"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your GridLayout in your xml with this

**Problem:** this `R.id.mainGrid` wasn't found in your xml, hence the null pointer exception

**Solution** Add the id `android:id="@+id/mainGrid"` to your Layout view

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        >
```

You can further educate yourself on null pointers here [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Cheers!

Comment: This solution just works... Thank you very much !